# android - setting the background of a textview in a table

Tags: android, layout, textview, tablelayout

Sorry if the question isn't informative enough.
I am coding an app for ICS. I decided to use a TableLayout to create a grid for users to click stuff in.
For each row, I put in several TextViews and an ImageView of a 1dp vertical border between each two of them, all done programmatically in a loop.
Now I made each TextView clickable. When it's clicked, its background changes to a blue drawable. However, I observe that the drawable does not fill the whole "grid" horizontally.
I think that the ImageView is perhaps occupying more space than it should (1dp). I have come up with or found many ways to stretch the TextViews but neither has worked for me.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the loop I am using - I know it's a bit complicated so I didn't post it :P The variables are already declared properly, of course.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        tr = new TableRow(ctxt);
        tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){ //add the text from an array
            tv = new TextView(ctxt);
            tv.setText(a[6*i+j]:null);
            tv.setTextSize(16);
            tv.setPadding(0, 4, 0, 4);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setClickable(true);
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_background);
            tv.setTag(39+6*i+j);
            tv.setOnClickListener(this);
            tr.addView(tv, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2.0f));
            if(j<5){ //set the border
                border = new ImageView(ctxt);
                border.setImageResource(R.drawable.vert_border);
                tr.addView(border, new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.0f));
            }
        }
        tl2.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 48));
        if(i<4){ //horizontal border
            tr = new TableRow(ctxt);
            tr.setMinimumHeight(1);
            tr.setBackgroundColor(color.bg_gray);
            tl2.addView(tr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your code for more explanation so we help you for exact you want

Comment: just added - I was afraid it's too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...this solution was inspired by Alfi, but mostly discovered by myself.
I used a LayoutInflater to create the TableRow instead of constructing it.

```
tr = (TableRow) li.inflate(R.layout.tbrow, null, false);
```

where tbrow.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="293" >
</TableRow>
```

since weight sum cannot be set in the program.
the 293 here equals the total width of my TextViews and my ImageView borders. (48*6+1*5)
Then in the program I can set exactly the width I want.
As Alfi instructed, I set the width to zero then set the weight as the width I want.

```
tr.addView(tv, new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 48));
```

as for the border:

```
tr.addView(border, new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
```

Hope this helps somebody else who stumbles upon this page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use android:layout_weight attribute to allocate the space occupied by a view. You have to assign android:weigh_sum to the container[In your case it is Table Row]

<TableRow
    <----------
    <----------
    android:weigh_sum="1">
    <ImageView
    <----------
    <----------
    android:Layout_weight=".2" // occupies 20%of the TableRow container   

I hope this helps.
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, android:layout_width="0dip" set this attribute to the imageView and also other views in the TableRow container, all views in the container should be set to "0dip" width for layout_weight attribute to take effect.

Comment: but can I assign weight sum in my code? As you see, I am doing all that not through XML.

Comment: I assume you are setting the weight using "TableRow.LayoutParams (int w, int h, float initWeight)" constructor, if so set (int w) as 0 and give the % of weight for each child... I see in the code that tv is set to match_parent change this to 0.

Comment: Nicely done, I am glad its resolved. We can close this thread I guess.. Thanks for the update!!!